# facing problem in action mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

facing problem in action mailer. 
my mailer is

```
  def registration_confirmation(user)
    subject    "Password Reset Instructions"
    from        "sender_email_id@test.com"
    recipients  user.email
    content_type "text/html"
    body        "RESET your Password"
  end
```

Settings for mailer are

```
require 'development_mail_interceptor'

ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => "domain.in",
  :user_name            => "admin@domain.in",
  :password             => "PASSWORD",
  :authentication       => "plain",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}

ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = "localhost:3000"
Mail.register_interceptor(DevelopmentMailInterceptor) if Rails.env.development?
```

and my controller is `UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@new_user).deliver`

The mail is not going to the user.email , it is always going to admin@domain.in

I am using mail-v 2.2.19 and rails 3.0.9

please help.

Answer (score 1):

try adding this line(works for me):

```
mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Password Reset Instructions")
```

to your registration_confirmation method

```
def registration_confirmation(user)
    from        "sender_email_id@test.com"
    content_type "text/html"
    body        "RESET your Password"
    mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Password Reset Instructions")
end
```